# Conflicting types for '-(bool)validateToolbarItem:(NSToolbarItem *)theItem'

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have this code:

```
- (BOOL) validateToolbarItem:(NSToolbarItem *)theItem {
    BOOL enable = NO;

    if (1 == [theItem tag]) {
        enable = YES;
    }

    return enable; 
}
```

And I get this warning, although the program runs as expected:

```
Conflicting types for '-(bool)validateToolbarItem:(NSToolbarItem *)theItem'
```

How can I get rid of this warning? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somewhere else, probably in the header, you have the type for the method declared with `bool` (lowercase). You need to make it consistent with the defined method which uses uppercase `BOOL`.

`BOOL` is what is commonly used in objective-C.

Comment: There is no bool(lowercase) declared in any of the header.

Comment: @Vinpai where is your method validateToolbarItem: declared (not defined)? What is the declaration? What is the return type?

Comment: I have overriden NSToolBarItem validation protocol method to validate the toolbar item.

Comment: @Vinpai How many places does this method show up in your code? Is the return type `BOOL` in all cases?